# iOS: drop shadow with sharp edges

Tags: ios, core-graphics, shadow, dropshadow

I'm trying to add some shadows to one of my views and what I would like to achieve is drawing shadows only on one side and let them have sharp edges. No I've tried quite a few methods without any luck (using the shadow related properties of the view's CALayer + UIBezierPaths). However, iOS is always rendering a shadow with soft edges like this:

[image]

But what I really want to acchieve is something like this (without round corners and sharp edges on the sides **except one**):

[image]

Is there any elegant way to do this or will I have to draw the shadow myself using CoreGraphics?

PS: I forgot to mention, my view should actually be a custom UIButton, so overriding drawRect: would be a pain here

Comment: Hey YllierDev, could you please explain what your final code block looked like to achieve the above affect? I'm trying to learn how I am able to apply a drop shadow on my button with only showing the drop shadow on the right. If you could help me that would be awesome! thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've experienced a mask removing the shadow from view...so maybe you can try that.

```
    CALayer *mask = [[[CALayer alloc] init] autorelease];
    mask.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    mask.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, yellowView.bounds.size.width + shadowWidth, yellowView.bounds.size.height);
    yellowView.layer.mask = mask;
```

Comment: that sounds like a good suggestion. Why didn't I think about that... (facepalm)

Comment: Thank you Matt, using a mask was the right option. I really don't know why I didn't think abut that :D

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to be changing is the shadowRadius value - set that to zero and you should get the sharp edge you're looking for:

```
myView.layer.shadowRadius = 0;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but setting the shadowRadius to 0 would result in all edges being sharp, but I want sharp edges except on one side.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part of the question.  Have you tried using something like this yellowView.layer.shadowPath = CGRectMake(yellowView.bounds.size.width, 0, 1, yellowView.bounds.size.height);?  That might get you part of the way, but with a blur, the blur may go up and down beyond the bounds of the view.

Comment: If you can't override drawRect, then you're probably going to have to use a subview to achieve this, so the parent view is clipsToBounds = YES, and you have a subview for the yellow patch, where it's width is let's say 10 pixels short of the right edge, and you put your shadow on the yellow patch.  If you think that might work for you, I'll write it up in a more complete answer.